# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 + promise error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm just getting started with MongoDB. After installing it and running the code I'm getting an error.

Code:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/yelp-camp', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", ()=> {
    console.log("Database connected");
});
```

Error:
[First part of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Inh.png)

[Second part of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQoB5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ECONNREFUSED usually means that your services isn't available. Is seems to me that your mongodb isn't running or is listening on a different port

Maybe try port 27018 or 27019
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/